# Cheapest/fastest way to raise a Mind Mag?

Tags: phantasy-star-online

On PSOBB, I want to raise a Mag with a Mind value as high as possible.

I read that it’s possible to get a Mag with **195** Mind, but that requires to use a certain Mag Cell on Mag level 5, which means that the Mag won’t learn any Photon Blasts. As I can’t get this Mag Cell and I’d like to have PBs, this is no option.

According to many guides, the hightest Mind value without using a Mag Cell would be **185**, but some claim that it would be possible to get **186** (by putting the Mag into the bank after every single feed).

Is it true that you can get 186 Mind by such a method? But as this would take so much longer, this is quite a disproportionate effort.

**So what is the cheapest/fastest way to raise a Mag to Mind 185?**

---

The guide [Vulpes' Maximum Single Stat Mag](http://www.pso-world.com/sections.php?op=viewarticle&artid=1026) requires to feed for level 50 (in total):

- 388 Monofluids
- 5 Antiparalysis
- 1 Difluid
- 76 Trifluids

Those 76 Trifluids cost a pretty penny, but it’s probably really fast. Or is there an even faster way?

The guide [Ultimate Mag FAQ](http://www.ign.com/faqs/2003/phantasy-star-online-episode-i-ii-ultimate-mag-faq-400348) only requires to use Monofluids and Difluids.

It doesn’t use any Trifluids, so it should be way cheaper than the first guide, but is there an even cheaper way?

Comment: I haven't raised a mag in years, but I know that it depends on your section ID and class. This kind of stuff takes tons of research though.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero: Oh, yes. So for feeding it, I can transfer the Mag to character(s) with the needed race/class/gender/SID combination.

Comment: Nevermind about SID, that's only for the rare mag evolutions. Only class matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking over the chart and it looks like you're stuck with that specific feeding plan. You can verify this by looking at stage 2 feeding charts. If you choose to feed the mag anything other than the specified items, it will cause the mag's defense to level. In fact, when the mag evolves at 35, the feeding guide has it's defense listed as 94% of the way to leveling. This is after the 76 Trifluids, 5 Antiparalysis and 1 Difluid.

Where you will actually save some money is during 35-50. If it evolved on a Hunter it will get +10 from monofluids, Forces get +9, and Rangers will get a measly +4.

---

If you'd like to do the research yourself, you'll need: [Feeding charts for all mags](http://www.pso-world.com/sections.php?op=viewarticle&artid=1021),  [Hunter mag chart](http://www.pso-world.com/sections.php?op=viewarticle&artid=1240), [Force mag chart](http://www.pso-world.com/sections.php?op=viewarticle&artid=1238), [Ranger mag chart](http://www.pso-world.com/sections.php?op=viewarticle&artid=1241).

From here, you'll want to figure out what you can feed your mag that will only raise its mind. Once your mag reaches level 10,35, and 50 it can evolve.

The other thing you'll probably need is MagFarm, an application that simulates mag feeding so you are less likely to mess up. Unfortunately I could only find a link to the [Mac binaries](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11937/magfarm). (please be careful with the linked site, I cannot test it)

If you're able to find a working version of this application, then it's very simple and even has an Undo button.